# Wäre at the beginning of an article title

Tags: subjunctive

Zum Beispiel:

> Wäre Hamburg doch nur das größte Problem der CDU

Source: https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2020-02/buergerschaftswahl-hamburg-cdu-wahlniederlage

Das sieht nicht wie ein Konjuktiv II aus. Was bedeutet diese Überschrift? Und wie könnte man den Satz nach Englisch übersetzen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Das Verb *wäre* ist genau der Konjunktiv II von *sein*.

   > Indikativ: Ich **bin** in Wien.
   >   Konjunktiv I: Egon sagt, ich **sei** in Wien.
   >   Konjunktiv II: Ach, **wäre** ich doch in Wien.
2. Die Überschrift bedeutet, dass der Wunsch besteht, dass der Misserfolg bei der Wahl in Hamburg das größte Problem der CDU sein möge. (Jemand wünscht sich, dass alle anderen Probleme der CDU kleiner wären.) Leider hat die CDU aber noch viele andere Probleme, wovon einige noch größer als Hamburg sind. Dieser Wunsch ist unerfüllbar, denn er betrifft den gegenwärtigen Zustand. Gegenwärtig wird es allgemein als Faktum angesehen, dass die CDU jetzt gerade mehrere Probleme hat, die größer als die Wahlschlappe in Hamburg sind.

   Um so einen unerfüllbaren Wunsch auszudrücken, verwendet man den grammatischen Modus [Irrealis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis). Im Deutschen gibt es den Irrealis nicht als eigenständigen Modus, allerdings gibt es ihn als sprachliches Konzept, das im Deutschen durch den [Konjunktiv II](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Irrealis) realisiert ist.
3. Englisch ist zwar eine Fremdsprache für mich, ich wage aber trotzdem eine Übersetzung:

   > If only Hamburg was the biggest problem of CDU

Comment: Wenn mich mein Englisch nicht im Stich lässt, müsste es eher lauten *If Hamburg **were** the biggest problem of CDU*.

Comment: @RHa: Du verunsicherst mich. Ich dachte: Hamburg = 3rd person singular; was = 3rd person singular, were = 3rd person plural. (*"**It was** a problem"* vs. *"**They were** problems"*)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ihr habt beide Recht. "were" ist nicht nur 3rd person plural past sondern auch 3rd person plural subjunctive (engl. Subjunktive ist quasi gleich deutscher Konjunktiv)... aber der Subjunctive ist ugs. fast ausgestorben.

Comment: @Max: Didn't you mean "3rd person *singular* subjunctive"? "3rd person plural subjunctive" doesn't seem to be relevant to the question. see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/44707/247654

Comment: @EricDuminil: yes, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Der Konjunktiv II wird hier für die Formulierung eines (irrealen) Wunsches verwendet, siehe [hier](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/verben/konjunktiv). In romanischen Sprachen würde man den Optativ setzen.

Answer (score 2):

Grammar, or the literal tranlation is not helpful without knowing the context in this case, but either way, here it is:

> If only Hamburg was CDU's biggest problem

It is technically indeed Konjunktiv II (ist → wäre). But it doesn't express wishful thinking, imagination, or courtesy.

Technically, this headline could mean many things, depending on context. It *could* for example mean the author is aware of bigger problems but wishes that the CDU indeed did not have these, and that the poor outcome at the election (not surprising in any way, to be honest) was something they could just ignore.

In reality, the author, being an author of a known left-aligned paper, is being spiteful. It's scoff, not compassion, nor wishing. The author wishes to further *inflate* other existent or non-existent problems (which he does in a far from impartial way, too, in the article).

Although the article is called "an analysis" and tries to mask itself as that, it is of course far from being that. Without knowing where the line came from, it is however hard, if not impossible, to know.

Politics are probably a bad thing to read for practicing German at this time because it is troublesome to find something that isn't misleading or outright lies.

Comment: I remember that my English teacher in the 9th or 10th grade once stated that an unreal wish like that was the only situation where you could break the rule "never use *would* after *if*". Unless he was wrong, you might replace "was" in Damon's answer with "would be".